# passing array value from .as script to comboBox of .mxml code

Tags: actionscript-3, flexbuilder

How to pass `array` value from **.as** to the `comboBox` of **.mxml** code?
I am calling  a .as script in **.mxml** code. I have `<mx:ComboBox>` for which thr dataprovider is an `array` value coming from the same **.as** file. How to bind this to `combobox`?
My both Codes are as follows:

```
// ActionScript file

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.FileFilter;
    import flash.net.FileReference;
    import flash.net.FileReferenceList;

    import mx.controls.Alert;

        private var fr:FileReferenceList;
        private var fls:Array;

        private function folder():void
        {
            fr = new FileReferenceList();
            fr.browse([new FileFilter("Zip Files", "*.zip")]);
            fr.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, listZipFiles);            
        }

        private function listZipFiles(e:Event):void
        {
            Alert.show("selectHandler: " + fr.fileList.length + " files");          
            var file:FileReference = new FileReference;
            fls = new Array();

            for (var i:uint = 0; i < fr.fileList.length; i++) 
            {
                file = FileReference(fr.fileList[i]);
                //Alert.show("File Name: " + fr.fileList[i]);
                Alert.show("File Name: " + file.name);
                fls.push(file);                         
            }
            Alert.show("fls: " + fls);
            gotoCmboBx(fls);
        }

        private function gotoCmboBx(arr:Array):Array
        {

        }
        private function getShpFiles(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

        }
```

and .mxml code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:Script source="Asset/folder.as" />
    <mx:Button x="10" y="10" label="My Button" width="122" height="31" id="myButton" click="folder()"/>
    <mx:ComboBox x="10" y="49" id="cbobx" dataProvider="{fls}"  ></mx:ComboBox>

</mx:Application>
```

Comment: By all means do NOT post any code. I much prefer to guess.

Comment: That was sarcasm Post your code so we can help you.

Comment: i tried to enter a code...i have to take an another training for "how to post a code here"

Comment: just copy/paste your code in, select the code, and hit the `{}` above the input window. You'll see `{}` to the right of **B** *I*

Comment: posted my code finally...wasn't that hard...it was just 2 much for the last night....Thanks Jackson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Array](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html) class is a top level Object and does not implement [IEventDispatcher](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/IEventDispatcher.html), which is required for binding.  Try using an [ArrayCollection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html) instead.

**Update:** To add items to an ArrayCollection you can either use the [addItem()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#addItem%28%29) method, or you can use the `push()` method of the Array that ArrayCollection wraps in the property [source](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html#source).  However, whenever you make direct changes to the `source` Array, you need to call the refresh() method.

```
myArr.source.push(myFileReference);
myArr.refresh();
```

The `addItem()` method is preferred.

**Update 2:** mx:ComboBox has a property [labelField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/ComboBox.html#labelField) which determines what field from the items in the `dataProvider` to use.  In order to display the `name` of a FileReference object, the following should do it:

```
<mx:ComboBox dataProvider="{fls}" labelField="name"/>
```

Comment: but i can not use push function in case of arraycollection.

Comment: thanks now i m passing the files object to another arraycollection which is bindable to combobox cbobx.

Comment: there is another problem i can get the file objects from .as cript to a combobox but without their names.how to get the files names along with file referances? The .as code is:

Comment: @Kanchan - I added answers to your follow up questions.  In general, it sounds like you would benefit from working through Adobe's Flex-In-A-Week series, which covers a bunch of techniques relating to data-centric apps.  That's just my personal recommendation.

Comment: ,Thanks for your ans and suggestion. <mx:combobox> is now taking filenames when i mention labelField="name"

Comment: @Kanchan - If I've adequately answered your original question, an accepted answer would be appreciated.